# Disable dragging in MPAndroidChart PieChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How can I disable the dragging gesture in a `PieChart`. I want the chart to be like a static image.

Comment: Have you tried: `view.setEnabled(false)`?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Yes, I've tried it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `chart.setTouchEnabled(false);` More details can be found [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart).

Comment: Your answer is too short, please update it with more information. At least, links to FAQ. If you're sure that this is a solution then explain it.

Comment: This solution doesn't disable ONLY the rotation. If you want to keep the other possible interactions, use `pieChart.setRotationEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 14):

If you want to disable only the dragging gesture, you can now use

```
pieChart.setRotationEnabled(false);
```

As seen [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/61).